# Allowable list of vertice degrees in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Determine if the following is an allowed list of vertex degrees for a graph (or multigraph, connected or disconnected.) If it is, how many edges does the graph have?

$2,2,3,4,6,7$

I said that this would be allowable since the sum of degrees of vertices is even. $(2+2+3+4+6+7) / 2 = 12~$ edges. Would this be a reasonable explanation?

$2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10$

I said that this would be allowable since the sum of degrees of the vertices is even and divided by two it would have $25$ edges. Would this be a reasonable explanation?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the parentheses. Are you asking four different questions? You want do know if the given list of degrees is feasible for (a) a connected graph, (b) a disconnected graph, (c) a connected multigraph, (d) a disconnected multigraph?

Comment: Indeed, isn't every integer sequence the degree sequence of some disconnected multigraph?